# Overwriting a text file from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Now if you write the text and click on the save `button`, `OpenFileDialog` will appear. If you finish something in the same document and click on the `save button` again, you need to select the save location again. How to make that when saving the same file you do not need to create a new file each time, and just overwrite the current one? Sorry for my English.

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Rich Text File | *.rtf";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Need a little more information, its not clear what you are trying to do. File.WriteAllLines("<Save Path Here>", richTextBox1.Lines); Where:"<Save Path Here>" might be: "C:\\Temp\\RTF.txt" but I am not able to make out what you're doing with the colours.

Comment: Colors are not important. I edited the question.

Comment: if i understand your requirement correctly, what do you like to achieve is if file exists then SaveFileDialog need to reopen for reselecting the path

Comment: If I have already saved the file, then I do not need to re-specify the save location, but simply overwrite the file. As in all text editors and as in MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is, you just need to remember the last file path you saved and not display the dialog again the next time around; something like this should help:

```
void Main()
{
    Save();
}

private string _filePath = "";
void Save()
{
    var overwrite = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filePath))
    {
        var res =
        MessageBox.Show("Would you like to overwrite your last saved file?", "Overwrite?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
        MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly, false);

        if (res == DialogResult.Cancel) return;
        if (res == DialogResult.No) overwrite = false;
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes) overwrite = true;
    }

    if (!overwrite)
    {
        var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Rich Text File|*.rtf";
        var res = sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (res != DialogResult.OK) return;
        _filePath = sfd.FileName;
    }

    // do the richTextBox.SaveFile(_filePath) here.

}
```

In this example it:

```
CHECK IF FILE PATH ALREADY SET
IF NOT THEN
  ASK USER IF THEY WANT TO OVERWRITE THE LAST FILE
  IF CANCEL THEN DON'T SAVE
  IF YES THEN SET OVERWRITE TO TRUE
  IF NO THEN SET OVERWRITE TO FALSE
END IF
CHECK IF OVERWRITING
IF OVERWRITING THEN
  SHOW SAVE FILE DIALOG
  IF USER DIDN'T CLICK OK THEN DON'T SAVE
  IF USER CLICKED OK, SET THE NEW FILE PATH TO USE
END IF
SAVE THE FILE USING THE NOW-REMEMBERED FILE PATH
```

Comment: I do not need a MessageBox. And what does it mean "do the richTextBox.SaveFile (_filePath) here."?

Comment: Just put your usual save code there: `richTextBox1.SaveFile(**_filePath**);`

Comment: @Kaya And I've added the messagebox because chances are you don't want your users to be unable to change their mind about overwriting the file at some point. Always give your users options, they appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; 
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files"; 
saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true; 
saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true; 
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"; 
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2; 
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;       

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
   textBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;             
} 
}
```

Example from: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/savefiledialog-in-C-Sharp/

Might help some?

Comment: This is not what I need. Your method asks you to specify an existing file. I need that when I have already saved the file, I no longer needed to show it a save location. As in MS Word.

Comment: And are you over writing the same file or appending to it? Yes, there is no point using a Save File Dialog if you don't need to specify the Location! If the file is already saved, then you already know the location. As in my comment above, you would be better off to use: File.WriteAllLines("<Save Path Here>", richTextBox1.Lines); Where:"<Save Path Here>" might be: "C:\\Temp\\RTF.txt"

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string filePath = string.Empty;
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            //write to file
            FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            ms.WriteTo(file);
            file.Close();
            ms.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Rich Text File | *.rtf";
            sfd.OverwritePrompt = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName);
                filePath = sfd.FileName;

            }
        }
    }
```

you can use sfd.OverwritePrompt = false; property to avoid prompt messagebox if file already exists, is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: This method still use OpenFileDialog. When you first save, of course, there must be an OpenFileDialog, but with the second save, the file simply needs to be overwritten without calling OpenFileDialog.

Comment: for that you need to save the path somewhere in your program, updated my answer, it will perfectly fix your requirement i guess

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, but why when you first save everything is good, and the second (overwrite) seems to change the format. If, after the first save, open the file through MS Word, then everything is fine, but after the second save (overwrite) all words change to the -? Sign. My native language is russian. And also when you click the open button and select a saved file, an error occurs - an invalid file format. It seems that the format changes when you overwrite.

Comment: please debug and check filePath on second save and compare this with the actual path